# force angularjs to instantiate a controller on "back"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i tell my angularjs app to navigate backwards

```
$window.history.back();
```

i see that the previous view's controller is being reused.  is there a way to force angularjs to instantiate a new controller?

i am using a ngView element on the page and populating it with templates.  perhaps there is a way to dictate to the router that a new controller should be instantiated each time.

(why is stackoverflow insisting on more words before i can submit my questions?....)

Comment: Have you considered resetting your controller rather than trying to create a whole new one?

Comment: could you elaborate?  angular seems to handle this on its own.  i am not sure how to influence controller instantiation OR "resetting"

Comment: you could add a routeChangeStart handler which calls a method on your controller which resets all of it's values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be investigating the `$templateCache`. I believe in many cases, Angular does instantiate a "new" controller on this event, but your template cache injects the data/state of the view when you use the history service.

Really, it all depends on scope... if your forward progress (app interaction) keeps your state and view within or underneath (as a child of) the same scope, the controller will never be destroyed, however if you leave the scope, it should clean up. (this is actually javascript, and Angular wraps that behavior with `$scope`).  The `$templateCache` either way will rebuild the state, including data models within your view's assigned controller.

You would have to go about this by intercepting the history event taken, search the $cacheFactory or $templateCache for the key/value pair matching the view in question, then run:

```
$templateCache.remove('keystring');
```

prior to allowing the history event to execute.  via the `$cacheFactory`, you can use `$templateCache.get()` to return information about the views you have cached.

Check out: 
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory